# React-leaflet GeoJSON `onClick`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, python-re, react-leaflet

`GeoJSON` components does not seem to have an `onClick` handler, global to the component.
If you add `onClick`, it will work, but TypeScript will trigger an error.

Sample code:

```js
import { GeoJSON } from "react-leaflet";
const MyComponent = () => (
    <GeoJSON
      key={id}
      onClick={console.log}
      data={geometry}
    />
)
```

Same question applies to `style` by the way, there does not seem to be a way to have a global style.
Maybe I should use a `ref`? Adding a wrapper `div` doesn't work.

How to set a global `onClick` handler to the `GeoJSON` component?

Version: `react-leaflet@2.7.0`

Answer (score 2):

You should add your click handler in an 'onEachFeature' function, and pass that to the prop on your component:

```
 function onEachFeature(feature, layer){
      if(feature.properties){
        layer.bindPopup("Your text or whatever")
      }
      layer.on({
          mouseover: onMouseOver,
          mouseout: onMouseOut,
        click: zoomToFeature
      });
    }

<GeoJSON data={points} pointToLayer={pointToLayer} pathOptions={markerStyles} onEachFeature={onEachFeature}
```

Answer (score 0):

And I've found the answer as soon as I've asked the question: it is `onclick`, lowercase, not `onClick`. This is not the usual `onClick` prop.

I couldn't find any clear documentation however.